# Optimize dopar R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, doparallel

I want to loop over 116 groups (i) to do the follow:

```
r<- foreach(i=unique(Error$scidx),.combine = c) %dopar% {
  numerator=sum(P1new[Error$scidx==i])+sum(P2new[DATA$scid==i])
  denominator=sum(P1old[Error$scidx==i])+sum(P2old[DATA$scid==i])
  probab=exp(numerator-denominator)
  if (runif(1)<probab){
    Change=1
  } else{
    Change=0
  }
  list(i,Change)
}
```

I am requesting 4 cores and it takes me long to run each time. I suspect it is because the data Error, P1new, P1old contain 700,000 observations. Is it true? Is there any way I can speed up the process? Or, my code has something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an example of the data you are working on. Few rows would be good. Provide `dput()` of your data frame.

Comment: And, P1new, P1old contains a column vector of 700,000 observations

Comment: For "Error":

structure(list(.......), .Names = c("fromid", "toid", "rowid", 
"scidx", "toerror1old", "toerror2old", "toerror1new", "toerror2new", 
"scidy", "fromerror1old", "fromerror2old", "fromerror1new", "fromerror2new", 
"differror1old", "differror1new", "differror2old", "differror2new"
), sorted = "fromid", class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000046e0788>)

Comment: For "DATA": structure(list(......), .Names = c("scid", "aid", "Y", "boy_mumdegree", 
"boy_daddegree", "girl_mumdegree", "girl_daddegree", "peergpa", 
"peergender", "peerage", "peerblack", "peerother", "parentboth", 
"gpa", "grade", "female", "age", "black", "other", "multirace", 
"mum_degree", "mum_pro", "dad_degree", "dad_pro", "comm_race", 
"comm_crime", "income", "miss_pdegree", "miss_ppro", "parent_both", 
"degree", "degreewhite", "degreeblack", "degreeother", "Freq"
), row.names = 7:10, class = "data.frame")

Comment: please add dput(DATA) and dput(Error) in the question.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understood. The output I attached are the results of dput(Error) and dput(DATA). Am I missing something?

Thanks again